# How can a nodejs app connect to one of the failover MySQL servers when using clustering (NDBCluster or Galera)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, galera

If I have one MySQL server, I will use [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) to connect as follows:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: mysql.local,
  port: "3306",
  database: "my_db",
  user: "my_user",
  password: "my_password",
  charset : "utf8mb4"
});
```

This all works fine.

But let's say I change this set up so it uses clustering - either via NDBCluster or Galera - so there are a few different hosts available for writing and reading.

What `host` should be used in the node app?

What happens if this host goes down? How can my node app connect to one of the backup hosts?

I've tried finding an answer on this, but I cannot find anything.

Comment: According to the [Galera docs](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/) its usage should be transparent to the client app (in this case, Node)

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've seen that phrasing before (should be transparent to the client app) but I still can't find an answer to what `host` I should put in my nodejs app.

Comment: `NDB` and `Galera` are radically different animals.  Either decide which one and let's discuss that one, or phrase the question as "which is better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found a simple solution which works well.

1. I chose Galera as the solution. You can read a nice walkthrough here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-galera-cluster-with-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04
2. I then use the following code for DB queries. Note I am still using mysqljs/mysql:

   ```
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   var poolCluster = mysql.createPoolCluster();

   poolCluster.add('node1', {
     host : 'node1',
     database: 'my_db',
     user : 'my_user',
     password : 'my_password',
     charset : 'utf8mb4'
   });

   poolCluster.add('node2', {
     host : 'node2',
     database: 'my_db',
     user : 'my_user',
     password : 'my_password',
     charset : 'utf8mb4'
   });

   poolCluster.add('node3', {
     host : 'node3',
     database: 'my_db',
     user : 'my_user',
     password : 'my_password',
     charset : 'utf8mb4'
   });

   poolCluster.getConnection(function (err, connection) { 
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           connection.query('SELECT * FROM some_table', function(err, rows) {
               if (err) {
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
                   console.log(rows);
                   connection.release();
               }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Note in this setup if one or more of the database nodes go down, the queries will be routed to whichever node is alive. When the failed nodes restart, any data they're missing will be synced from one of the live servers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand your question now and some of it might be more appropriate to ServerFault in truth, but I’ll give you the developers view here and if you run into trouble setting up the infrastructure, ask there. :)

So, the what host and what happens question depends a bit on which of the cluster techs you setup and how you set it up, but using Galera as an example, the cluster sits behind a load balancer of some sort.  Galera supports one of its own, or HAProxy, or one called Pen.  That’s the host you’ll point your app to.

When deploying the load balancer, you should actually deploy two or more and have them configured for dynamic failover.  [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-haproxy-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04) has a nice tutorial on doing this for HAProxy in front of web servers but the principle is the same.

Comment: or dba.stackexchange